# "and in all places their lot is..." - meaning of "lot" here

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Rading a story from C.A. Smith, I am unsure of the meaning in the following sentence (in bold):

> For Melchior was one of those who are born with an immedicable
> distaste for all that is present or near at hand; one of those who
> have drunk too lightly of oblivion and have not wholly forgotten the
> transcendent glories of other aeons, and the worlds from which they
> were exiled into human birth; so that their furtive, restless thoughts
> and dim, unquenchable longings return obscurely toward the vanishing
> shores of a lost heritage. The earth is too narrow for such, and the
> compass of mortal time is too brief; and paucity and barrenness are
> everywhere; **and in all places their lot is a never-ending
> weariness**.

What does "lot" means here? None of the dictionary meanings seem to fit properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [meaning](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lot) in this case is:

> **the quality of someone's life and the experiences that they have:**
>
> - *They should do something to improve the lot of the lowest-paid workers.*
> - *Do you think he's happy with his lot?*

Comment: hmm but who is "they" in my example?

Comment: @JohnV "they" is the "such" in "the earth is too narrow for **such**" (and tracing further backward, this corresponds to "one of **those who are born with...**" in the first sentence).